# html5 - Draggable Input Elements

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlets

I have a couple of issues creating dragable elements and reading them from a Servlet.

I'm creating a simple newsportal/blog, and one of the requirements is that I can create different sections to classify articles. An administrator also must be able to rearrange, from the web application, the order in which sections are displayed on screen.

So, for this, I figured a list where all elements were draggable was fitting. However, I have stumbled upon the issue that I can't read the final order from the servlet.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
<form action="OrderSection" method="post">

    <ul>
        <% for (Section u : listSection) {%>
        <input style="display: none;" 
               id="idSection" name="idSection-<%= i%>" type="number"
               required="required" value="<%= u.getIdSection()%>" />
        <li draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStarted(event)" 
            ondragover="draggingOver(event)" 
            ondrop="dropped(event)"><%= u.getNameSection()%></li>
        <input style="display: none;" 
               id="orderSection" name="orderSection-<%= i%>" type="number"
               required="required" value="<%= i%>" />
        <%i++;%>
        <% } %>
    </ul>

    <input name="total" hidden="hidden" value="<%= listSeccion.size()%>"/>
    <input name="step" hidden="hidden" value="v"/>
    <input type="submit" title="Aceptar"/>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var source;

    function dragStarted(evt) {
//start drag
        source = evt.target;
//set data
        evt.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", evt.target.innerHTML);
//specify allowed transfer
        evt.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
    }

    function draggingOver(evt) {
//drag over
        evt.preventDefault();
//specify operation
        evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
    }

    function dropped(evt) {
//drop
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
//update text in dragged item
        source.innerHTML = evt.target.innerHTML;
//update text in drop target
        evt.target.innerHTML = evt.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
    }

</script>
```

The specific issues I have are:

1. How do I read this elements on the Servlet, since they are li and not an input of any kind?
2. How do I read them **in the proper order**? Because DnD changes the data in the elements, but not their names, I can't think of a way of programmatically reading them in the proper order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just loop through the list before submitting the form and store the values in a array and pass  that to your server.

```
var listarray = [];
$("ul li").each(function() { listarray.push($(this).text()) });
```

The options will be in order in the array. You can encode that to string, JSON or something in pass it to your server.

This example uses JQuery.

Comment: I never thought of this option...thank you, it worked wonders